# Selenium - Testng : SoftAssert to be called inside each method or inside @afterTest

Tags: java, testng

I am new to Selenium, using testNG framework.  Below is the code I am trying to understand

```java
@Test
public void softAssertionTest() {
    try{
        softAssert.assertTrue(name.equals("HardAssertionTest"));
        softAssert.assertEquals(1, 1,"Error 1");
        softAssert.assertEquals("a","b","Error ab");
        System.out.println("Line after assertions");
    } catch (Throwable t){
        System.out.println("+++++++++++");
        verificationErrors.append(t);
        System.out.println("Verification error - method1"+ verificationErrors);
    }

}

@Test
public void softAssertionTest2() {
    softAssert.assertTrue(name.equals("HardAssertionTest"));
    softAssert.assertEquals(3, 4,"Error 3,4");
    softAssert.assertEquals("c","d","Error cd");     
    System.out.println("Line after assertions method 2");
}

@AfterTest
public void afterTest(){
    softAssert.assertAll();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
        fail(verificationErrorString);
        System.out.println(verificationErrorString);
    }
}
```

Q1) I read it is not a good practice to do assertions in configuration methods. Rather do them in each test method. Hence I modify the code as below

```java
@Test
public void softAssertionTest() {
    try{
        softAssert.assertTrue(name.equals("HardAssertionTest"));
        softAssert.assertEquals(1, 1,"Error 1");
        softAssert.assertEquals("a","b","Error ab");
        System.out.println("Line after assertions");
        doSoftAssert();
    } catch (Throwable t){
        System.out.println("+++++++++++");
        verificationErrors.append(t);
        System.out.println("Verification error - method1"+ verificationErrors);
    }
}

@Test
public void softAssertionTest2() {
    try{
        softAssert.assertTrue(name.equals("HardAssertionTest"));
        softAssert.assertEquals(3, 4,"Error 3,4");
        softAssert.assertEquals("c","d","Error cd");     
        System.out.println("Line after assertions method 2");
        doSoftAssert();
    } catch (Throwable t){
        System.out.println("+++++++++++");
        verificationErrors.append(t);
        System.out.println("Verification error - method2"+ verificationErrors);
    }           
}

public void doSoftAssert(){
    softAssert.assertAll();
    /*String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
    fail(verificationErrorString);
    System.out.println(verificationErrorString);
    }*/
}
```

When I run this, I see calling `softAssert.assertAll()` from `softAssertionTest2()`  executes the assertions in `softAssertionTest1()` as well, duplicating the asserts. How can I have assertions being asserted only once?

Q2) Is appending the errors to `verificationErrorString` the right way or is it advisable to add these errors in a `HashMap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I have assertions being asserted only once?

Every test should instantiate its own `SoftAssert` object and it should not be shared across multiple `@Test` methods.

> Is appending the errors to `verificationErrorString` the right way or is it advisable to add these errors in a `HashMap`?

You should never wrap your assertions with a `try..catch` block because it can cause you to gobble exceptions and it adds a lot of boiler plate code to your tests. 
If your intent is basically to capture the verification messages, then you should be looking at sub-classing `org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert` where you:

- Override `org.testng.asserts.Assertion#onAssertSuccess` (if you want to capture passed assertions) and
- Override `org.testng.asserts.Assertion#onAssertFailure(org.testng.asserts.IAssert<?>, java.lang.AssertionError)`  (if you want to capture failed assertions)

Comment: Thank you for the guidance. I understood the first part clearly. Going to read about overriding Assertion. Could you please provide me an example

Comment: Take a look at either `SofAssert` or `LoggingAssert` class from TestNG. That should give you a clear idea. Also pls don't forget to accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: Thanks ..will look into those  classes. It took me a while to figure out how to accept the answers..